# Excel IF statement based on the highest value cell

Tags: excel, max

I have put together a spreadsheet used for scheduling and currently I have the following columns-

```
'Start Time' 'Job Details' 'Planned Print Time' Actual Print Time'
```

The time column is formatted as such `=A3+TIME(0, D3,0)` so that it utilises the planned print time and automatically update the next time time to coincide with previous finish time.

what I would like to do is have this formula use either 'planned print time' or 'actual print time' dependant on which value is higher.

hope this makes sense. thank you in advance for help.

Comment: What is the time column? Do you mean the 'start time' column?

Answer (score 0):

You can you use the if statement as long as the date formats you are using can be compared.

```
= if(date1 > date2, date1, date2)
```

This will return the highest date to the cell, again assuming your date fields can be compared.